# Dynamically add textbox and assign it's value from a function

Tags: javascript

I want to create n number of textboxes dynamically based upon the user input.
Each textbox must populate with a serial number.Here, what I have tried so far.

```
function generateSerial(sender,eventArgs){
        debugger;
        //var rw_Serail = stockin.rw_Serail;
        if(eventArgs.get_newValue()!="0"){
            if(eventArgs.get_newValue()!=eventArgs.get_oldValue()){
                create(eventArgs.get_newValue());
                //OpenWindow(null,null,"rw_Serial");
            }
        }
    }
```

Create will call a function and it's job is to create textboxes and assign a value.

```
function create(param) {
        debugger;
        var s= "";
        for(var i = 0; i < param; i++) {
            s+= `<input type="text" style="width:72%" name="txtSerial" value=${generateLicense()}>`
                   `<button type="button" style="margin-left: 5px;height: 24px;">Change</button>`; //Create one textbox as HTML
        }
        document.getElementById("dvserialNo").innerHTML=s;
    }
```

as name suggests generateLicense() will return a serial number..

```
function generateLicense() {
   return "abcd1234Etc..";
}
```

Now while running this code, I am getting this error..

In chrome

> Uncaught TypeError: generateLicense(...) is not a function

In firefox

```
TypeError: (("<input type=\"text\" style=\"width:72%\" name=\"txtSerial\" value=" + (intermediate value)) + ">") is not a function
```

Note: I want to create and assign it's value at the same time.
[image]

Comment: There should be apostrophes around the value element within the input tag. value = “${generateLicense}”

Comment: Sir,I did exactly that.Any other approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concatenate the two elements in `s+`. And, of course, as one of the answers suggested include quotes for `value="${generateLicense()}"`

```
s+= `<input type="text" style="width:72%" name="txtSerial" value="${generateLicense()}">`
 + `<button type="button" style="margin-left: 5px;height: 24px;">Change</button>`; //Create one textbox as HTML
```

Comment: ya also working without using double quote.But why do I have to Concatenate??@zer0

Comment: Well, if you don't want to concatenate, you can remove the back ticks separating them. So your code can be like this

`<input type="text" style="width:72%" name="txtSerial" value="${generateLicense()}"> <button type="button" style="margin-left: 5px;height: 24px;">Change</button>`